# Unexpected error when querying for a field from Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using React.js to query a field in a document from Firebase. However, when I try to get the data, I keep getting an error. The code, the collection on Firestore, and and the error message are below. How do I properly query specific fields of data without running into this error?

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { firestore } from '../../firebase/firebase.utils';

class Economics extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      name: firestore.collection('blog-categories').doc('8uVaHd22tT5oXSzpOOuj').get('name') 
    }
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        hi
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Economics;
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What happens when you change `.get('name')` to  `.get().then(function(doc) { if (doc.exists){ doc.name }});`

Comment: @SteffPoint I get an error: "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression". When I add return before `doc.name`, it returns an object when I want it to return the string that `name` points to.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#get) is proper reference for the API you are using.

When you enter parameter to `get` method API is expecting options object, so when you enter String "name" there you will get this error massage.

The method is asynchronous so you have to take value form DocumentSnapshot ([reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot)) object returned as Promise which result of the method.

I hope it will help!

UPDATE: As requested I'm adding example:

Firestore has collection `collection1` with document `doc1` that has field `field1` with value 'value1':

```
var Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
var db = new Firestore();

var docRef = db.collection("collection1").doc("doc1");

docRef.get().then(docSnap => {
    console.log(docSnap.data().field1);
    console.log(docSnap.get("field1"));
});
```

If you run this in `node` result is:

```
value1
value1
```

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! I'm still having trouble writing the line of code that would make the query, what would the code look like to create this query?